# How to store elements in Scala List inside a loop?

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections

I have initialized a `List` and then I have to store elements into this List inside a loop like this:

```
private var linkLength:List[Double] = List()
    for (index <- 0 to linkIds.size - 1) {
       linkLength += networkLinks.get(index).getLength
    }
```

The value of `networkLinks.get(index).getLength` is in `Double` also `linkLength`(variable initialized as List) is also in`Double`.
But I don't understand why I am getting this error

`Type mismatch, expected: String, actual: Double`

Tell me if I am doing something wrong and also provide me a suitable solution

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: Hi @godot , I have mentioned the error which is coming to me. However `networkLinks.get(index).getLength` is in Double but i don't know why i am getting type mismatch error.

Comment: You could use `::=` and it should work, but as @Dima mentioned, this is not how things are done in scala.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use mutable vars, and don't access lists by index (that's very inefficient).

```
val linkLength = networkLinks.map(_.getLength)
```